# Keras and Tensorflow: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'self' referenced before assignment

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am following a tutorial for TensorFlow and Keras.

When I run the following syntax:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(units=64, activation='relu', input_dim=100))
model.add(Dense(units=10, activation='softmax'))
```

(This is not full stacktrace as StackOverflow wont let me saying it has code only) 
I get following error:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
UnboundLocalError                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-30ebc8793948> in <module>()
      5 from keras.layers import Dense
      6 
----> 7 model.add(Dense(units=64, activation='relu', input_dim=100))

--> 164                     layer(x)
    165                     set_inputs = True
    166                 else:


/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/initializers.py in __call__(self, shape, dtype)
   self._message_listener.Modified()

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'self' referenced before assignment
```

Could this be because of python 3.7?

Comment: That is probably true, because it works on Python 3.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I had to uninstall and reinstall Python 3.6. Python 3.7 looks like it introduces unexpected behavior. Thankfully, my issue is now resolved.

Comment: You can switch between multiple versions of Python using `virtualenv` or sort by the way. No need to uninstall Python 3.7 if you need it for other projects.

Comment: Indeed. I got annoyed and uninstalled. So the bug exist for TF / Keras on that front.

Comment: This helped me solve my issue too.  Instead of uninstalling 3.7 and installing 3.6 I downloaded anaconda, created a virtual environment for 3.6 along with all the other dependancies.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The problem seemed to be with python 3.7. Instead of uninstalling 3.7 and installing 3.6 I downloaded anaconda, created a virtual environment for 3.6 along with all the other dependancies.